# Syntax error: Unexpected token in react while importing an component using React.lazy() method

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, code-splitting, dynamic-import, unexpected-token

Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/App.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (11:31)

```
   9 | import Fastfood from "./Fastfood";
  10 | import Billing from "./Billing";
> 11 | const Fruit = React.lazy(() => import("./Fruit"));
     |                                ^
  12 | const App = () => {
  13 |   const isLogin = true;
  14 |
```

@ ./src/index.js 13:11-27

Answer (score 2):

You can add [babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import) by running this command:

```sh
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

then add it to your babel (ie: `.babelrc` file) configuration:

```
{
  "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```